# How can I join two tables and exclude all items from one table that are in the other table?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have a maillist table which has all usernames, which is the primary key. I have a second table, Registry, which has username as a foreign key. I am doing a checkbox form pulling the names from SQL Server database and I want to exclude names from the list who are already in my Registry table. FYI, the Registry table is used to keep track of people who have signed up for golf events. The maillist table is the master table of all golf members.
The code below does not work.

```
SQL = "SELECT maillist.MAILID as maillist_mailid,maillist.L_NAME,maillist.F_NAME, "
          SQL=SQL &" registry.mailid as registry_mailid FROM maillist, registry "
          SQL=SQL &"WHERE maillist.mailid<>registry.mailid ORDER BY maillist.mailid, maillist.l_name"
```

Thanks,Dave

Answer (score 3):

Try this (versions of Sql Server 2005+):

```
SELECT MAILID
FROM maillist
EXCEPT
SELECT MAILID
FROM registry
```

or this (versions 2000+)

```
SELECT 
  maillist.MAILID as maillist_mailid,
  maillist.L_NAME,
  maillist.F_NAME
FROM maillist
WHERE MAILID NOT IN (SELECT MAILID FROM registry)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT
                     A.MailID
                    ,A.L_Name   
                    ,A.F_Name
FROM                MailList A
LEFT OUTER JOIN     Registry B
ON                  A.MailID = B.MailID
WHERE               B.MailID IS NULL
```

Comment: I think - this is the bad example - because you cannot be sure that registry-maillist has 1:1 relationship, thus - you can gain many duplicates

Comment: This query returns everyone who is in the maillist table but not in the Registry.